# Is there any class for weak References on iPhoneOS ==> none

Tags: iphone, weak-references

My APP received a big data that was used about twice times.
So, I think It`ll cause a memory problem.

In this case I use the WeakReference class on java.
But, I couldn`t find any class for weak references like java.

**Is there any class for weak refereces on iPhoneOS?**

Is this the only way in this case,
that using didReceiveMemoryWarning method and release code.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhoneOS SDK does not support garbage collection so classes that implement weak referencing are not really needed. What I would suggest is that you run your app through Instruments (Choose Run->Run WIth Performance Tools->Allocations from Xcode 3.2.3. This will help you understand the memory usage of your app and detect possible leaks.

Comment: Weak references are not synonymous with garbage collection

Comment: I thought some one need this case for caching or memory management.
U say it is not necessary.

Comment: @Terry I know. They can also be useful to prevent retain cycles etc. His WeakReference java class is mainly used in relation to GC.

Comment: Yes, I should be managing retain cycles in didReceiveMemoryWarning.
this is the similar roll of GC. so they won't implement this.
Please, write infomation for this thread when U found some implementation of this.
Thanks U.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use persistent storage, if you want to play with big data because memory will not allow you beyond its limit.